# Lucene with Java

Tags: java, lucene

How to add Lucene to Java application? I downloaded Lucene 4.8.1 and have an existing Java application that I am trying to develop using Eclipse. I am trying to add Lucene to my Java build path path. Can you please tell me, what part of the downloaded Lucene zip folder do I need to add to the build path? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The core functionality is handled by (you guessed it): `lucene-core-{version}.jar`.

Most applications also require `lucene-queryparser-{version}.jar` and `lucene-analyzers-common-{version}.jar`.

You should [try the demo](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/demo/overview-summary.html).  That covers some of this typical setup info, and gives you a good starting point, as far as learning to implement your search functionality with it.